# вставить переменную которой присвоен математический знак в формулу

Tags: javascript

**к примеру:** получаем значение кнопки по которой происходит клик `let z = this.getAttribute('value');`, и имеем формулу `let res = a + b;`.

**ВНИМАНИЕ ВОПРОС:** есть ли возможность вместо плюса втулить переменную `z`, во имя динамического изменения математического действия в формуле?*

Comment: есть, собираешь нужную строку и делаешь `eval` либо через конструктор функции.

Comment: switch по всем возможным операторам. Либо полноценный интерпретатор арифметических выражений)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть оператор `eval`, как упомянул товарищ [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy).
Но **eval - is evil**:

```js
let f = '2 + 2';

document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && this.value.trim() !== '') {
    calcIt (this.value);
    this.value = '';
  }
});

function calcIt (sign) {
  let _f = f.replace('+', sign);
  let result = eval(_f);
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = `${_f} = ${result}`;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='sign' />
<h3>Result</h3>
<span id='result'>2 + 2 = 4</span>
```

Или последовать совету товарища [@vp_arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth).
Этот вариант более безопасен из-за проверки (что можно сделать и с `eval`, впрочем) и работает в тех языках, где `eval` вообще нет:

```js
let f = [2, 3];

document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && this.value.trim() !== '') {
    calcIt (this.value);
    this.value = '';
  }
});

function calcIt (sign) {
  let _f = 0;
  
  switch (sign) {
    case '-':
      _f = f[0] - f[1];
      break;
    case '+':
      _f = f[0] + f[1];
      break;
    case '*':
      _f = f[0] * f[1];
      break;
    case '/':
      _f = f[0] / f[1];
      break;
    default:
      document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = `Неизвестный знак "${sign}"!`;
      return;
  }

  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = `${f[0]} ${sign} ${f[1]} = ${_f}`;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='sign' />
<h3>Result</h3>
<span id='result'>2 + 3 = 5</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариация на тему:

```js
let f = [2, 3];

document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13 && this.value.trim() !== '') {
    calcIt (this.value);
    this.value = '';
  }
});

function calcIt (sign) {
  let res = f[0] 
    * (sign==='*'?f[1]:1) / (sign==='/'?f[1]:1)
    + (sign==='+'?f[1]:0) - (sign==='-'?f[1]:0);
  
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = `${f[0]} ${sign} ${f[1]} = ${res}`;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='sign' />
<h3>Result</h3>
<span id='result'>2 + 3 = 5</span>
```

Comment: Задолбаешься в операторах, если вводить их побольше :)

Comment: Главное, соблюдать приоритеты =)

Answer (score 0):

Вот как получилось:

```
for (let itemBtn of btn){       
    itemBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        let a = parseInt(inp1.value);
        let b = parseInt(inp2.value);
        let c = this.getAttribute('value');
        let res = eval(`${a}  ${c}  ${b}`);

        span.innerHTML = res;
    });
}
```

Главное что работает.

Comment: Не забудьте про проверку что именно Вы передаёте в `eval`, а то быстро гадость вставят.

Comment: ну как же без этого!))))

Comment: ПАЧЕМУ мАдератор моё СПАСИБО всем за помощь удалил?

Comment: Это не модератор, а обычный участник. А удалил потому что не несёт смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: Спасибо тут не принято писать. Помог чей-то ответ - плюсуй и прими его (галочка слева от ответа), это лучшее спасибо.

Comment: хватит зарабатывать на правках моих  ответов )))

Comment: Участники с репутацией > 2000 ничего не зарабатывают на правках

Comment: 1) Тогда пишите грамотно. 2) После 2k репы мы ничего за это не получаем.

Comment: какие все строгие аж жуть ))

Comment: use strict ))))

Comment: @EvgeniyR, Если мы не ставим по десять смайлов в каждой строке - это не значит что мы тут сухари в костюмчиках Мистера Смита :)